# User script location linux (debian etch)

Tags: linux, debian

In the linux file system, where should user scripts be placed?

I'm thinking specifically python scripts to be called by cron.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

the  information i got:

```
/usr/local/sbin     custom script meant for root
/usr/local/bin      custom script meant for all users including non-root
```

chatlog snips from irc.debian.org #debian:

```
(02:48:49) c33s: question: where is the _correct_ location, to put custom scripts
for the root user (like a script on a webserver for createing everything needed 
for a new webuser)? is it /bin, /usr/local/bin,...? /usr/local/scripts is 
mentioned in (*link to this page*)
(02:49:15) Hydroxide: c33s: typically /usr/local/sbin
(02:49:27) Hydroxide: c33s: no idea what /usr/local/scripts would be
(02:49:32) Hydroxide: it's nonstandard
(02:49:53) Hydroxide: if it's a custom script meant for all users including 
non-root, then /usr/local/bin
(02:52:43) Hydroxide: c33s: Debian follows the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, 
with a very small number of exceptions, which is online in several formats at 
http://www.pathname.com/fhs/ (also linked from http://www.debian.org/devel/ and 
separately online at http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/fhs/fhs-2.3.html)
(02:53:03) Hydroxide: c33s: if you have the debian-policy package installed, it's 
also in several formats at /usr/share/doc/debian-policy/fhs/ on your system
(02:53:37) Hydroxide: c33s: most linux distributions follow that standard, though 
usually less strictly and with more deviations than Debian.
```

thanks go out to Hydroxide

Answer (score 19):

If you're talking about scripts created by a user that will be run from that users crontab, I typically put those in either a bin or scripts folder in the home directory, or if they're intended to be shared between users, a /usr/local/scripts directory.

Answer (score 8):

For whom it interests, the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) is a standards document and still a very good read. I describes the foundation for almost any Linux distribution and is officially endorsed e.g. by [Debian](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/fhs/fhs-2.3.html) and the Linux Standards Base (LSB).

You won't find any positive answer for that question, though, since ... it's not defined ;-). Only thing I can say: Don't put in /bin (neither in /usr/bin). /usr/local/scripts is unusual as well. $HOME/bin seems to be an acceptable place, iff the script is only used by this single user.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a strong beleiver that if a file is made by a user, it goes in his user directory (/home/username) if he didn't make it then it gets more complicated. I have in the past just put them in either /usr/local/bin, /bin, or /usr/local/scripts, I'm not sure about etch, but you need to check to make sure that /usr/local/scripts is actually in Cron's $PATH.

Answer (score 4):

The [Debian guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/ch-modify.en.html) can be quite useful when it comes to Ubuntu:

> Normally, programs install themselves in the /usr/local subdirectories. But, Debian packages must not use that directory, since it is reserved for system administrator's (or user's) private use

`/usr/local/bin` seems to be acceptable according to the guide.

Personally I put my scripts in `$HOME/.scripts`.

I wish that LSB would specifically address this question though.

Answer (score 2):

How about /home/username/bin?

Add ~/bin to $PATH and make the script executable with chmod +x filename.

Answer (score 2):

personally I prefer

```
/home/username/.bin
```

This way the bin folder is hidden but you can still add it to the PATH and execute all scripts with the x-bit inside.

I like my home directory to be clean (at first glance) with very few folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add paths to your crontab file as shown in a [previous cron-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204/why-doesnt-my-cron-job-work-properly#13220).