# How to cron job setup in Amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running my website. I need to setup a Cron Job to run my file every 12 hours.

if file setup via command line so please give a detail step wise.

Does anyone have any advise?

Comment: Same way you'd do it on any other server. An EC2 instance is just like any other server in terms of cron.

Answer (score 24):

I recently began using Amazon's linux distro on ec2 instances and after trying all kinds of things for cron all I needed was:
`sudo service crond start`
`crontab -e`
This allowed me to set a cron job as "ec2-user" without specifying the user.  For example:
`0 12 * * * python3 example.py`
In fact, specifying a user here prevented it from running.  I also posted this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931652/crontab-is-not-working-on-amazon-ec2-server/41976954#41976954).

Answer (score 4):

It's just normal `cron`.

See: [HowTo: Add Jobs To cron Under Linux or UNIX?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)