# Scheduling a Script To Run Daily and Storing Data AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a python script that runs and collects data and stores the data in a Dynamodb table.

I would like to figure out a way to get this script to run daily via amazon prime or a dedicated windows server.

I am new to AWS and this type of thing. I am open to all solutions available for something like this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to leave the python script running 24/7? Perhaps just have a timer while loop running that checks if a certain amount of time has passed, and if it has, then execute the part of the script to collect and store the data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use AWS Lambda to run your Script. To make your script run periodically you can use CloudWatch Event rule.

Find how to Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

Find Schedule Expressions Using Rate or Cron [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html)

Answer (score -1):

Running scripts at a set time is easily done in Linux with cronjobs.

This answer explains it
[How to cron job setup in Amazon ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806318/how-to-cron-job-setup-in-amazon-ec2)

In short it is no different from runnings crons on other linux instances