# Cron Not Working - Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron

I've got a cronjob that won't work. Well, I can't seem to get any of my cronjobs to work.

here is my entry in /etc/crontab

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/Rscript /home/myRScript.R
```

Executing this script via command line (/usr/bin/Rscript /home/myRScript.R) runs fine. The script is executable (chmod 775).

I've even tried something simple like:

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

I have the script running fine on my home desktop. But am attempting to migrate the same code to an Amazon EC2 instance and it won't run. I'm at a loss for what to do next.

I've pretty much read through:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work

And nothing seems to work.

Comment: Followed the example here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472173/cannot-get-cron-to-work-on-amazon-ec2

answered by Druvision. 

I was using /etc/crontab and for whatever reason that never worked. Using crontab -e worked.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the cause of this is that some versions of cron (including the amz-linux) require that there is an newline at the end of the crontab file. Please add a blank line at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

The OP mentions Ubuntu on ec2, but thought I'd post my answer for the same question when using Amazon's linux distro on ec2: after trying all kinds of things for cron all I needed was:
`sudo service crond start`
`crontab -e`
This allowed me to set a cron job as "ec2-user" without specifying anything other than the cron job itself.  For example:
`0 12 * * * python3 /home/ec2-user/example.py`
I also posted this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931652/crontab-is-not-working-on-amazon-ec2-server/41976954#41976954).