# Is it possible to have cron job running on Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I'm currently working on scrapping tool for information analysis and I put a cron job on AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu 14 TLS Server).

The cron job runs by executing Laravel artisan command.

Following is what I have entered in `crontab -e`.

```
0 20 * * * php /var/www/html/artisan data:get
```

But this doesn't run everyday and I found cron service has stopped for no reason.

Is it possible to have cron job on AWS Ec2 instance?

If not, what's the solution?

Comment: If the answer below is correct, can you mark it as such ? This would help other customers having the same question and looking for answers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, cron should just run on Amazon EC2 instances.
Did you look at the answers to this question ?
[Cannot get cron to work on Amazon EC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472173/cannot-get-cron-to-work-on-amazon-ec2)