# Run cron jobs in amazon web services for codeigniter function

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter-3

I want to call codeigniter function for every minute in amazon web services cron jobs.How do i do it.An help will be appreciated.

Comment: by `amazon web services`, did you mean `ec2`?

Comment: Yes ec2 for amazon web services

Comment: Install Crontab and then add Cron jobs

Comment: @Shadab, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472173/cannot-get-cron-to-work-on-amazon-ec2)